# Question for post: If $E \in \sigma(\mathcal{C})$ then there exists a countable subset $\mathcal{C}_0 \subset C$ with $E\in \sigma(\mathcal{C}_0)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have read this post:

[If $E \in \sigma(\mathcal{C})$ then there exists a countable subset $\mathcal{C}_0 \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ with $E \in \sigma(\mathcal{C}_0)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61617/if-e-in-sigma-mathcalc-then-there-exists-a-countable-subset-mathcalc)

And I'm wondering if there would be some difference if the collection $\mathcal{C}$ is uncountable. Actually, that question has been addressed at:

[$\sigma$-algebra generate by uncountable collection of subsets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965569/sigma-algebra-generate-by-uncountable-collection-of-subsets)

Will the hint given in the second link also work for uncountable collections? My intuition tells me that they are the same, however, the problems seems to be addressed differently. Any comments or suggestions that can help me understand what is going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The hint does not assume that $\cal C$ is countable.

The idea is that you want to show that $\bigcup\{\sigma\cal(C_0)\mid C_0\subseteq C\textrm{ countable}\}$ is actually $\sigma\cal(C)$, which would imply, in turn, that every element of $\sigma\cal(C)$ was generated by a countable subset.

There is another method of doing so, however, using transfinite induction and the fact that $\sigma\cal(C)$ has a very nice internal structure as a hierarchy of length $\omega_1$, where each stage is generated by countable unions of sets of previous stages, or complements of such unions. Then one can "trace back" any $E\in\sigma\cal(C)$ to a countable generating subset.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to clarify my understanding, $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra generated by an uncountable collection of sets named $\mathcal{C}$. Then, how can we conclude that such field is the same as that generated by the union you mentioned?. 
Sorry, i'm just new into this, so I'm trying my best to visualize it: so, if we call $\mathcal{M} =  \bigcup \{ \sigma(\mathcal{C}_0) :  \sigma(\mathcal{C}_0) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{C})  \text{ is countable}\}$, you are saying that $\mathcal{M} = \sigma(\mathcal{C})$. ?

Comment: Yes. That is the gist of the hint. First show that $\cal M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then it is clear that $\sigma\cal(C)\subseteq M$, so you only need to argue that the converse inclusion holds, for this use the property of $\sigma(X)$ as the least $\sigma$-algebra containing $X$ to finish the argument.

Comment: Okay, I think I can follow your explanation but, got this doubt now: Is $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ uncountable ? since the class it is generated from ($\mathcal{C}$) is also uncountable ?

Comment: Yes, why shouldn't it be uncountable? In fact, one can prove that any infinite $\sigma$-algebra is uncountable, even if $\cal C$ is countable.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I appreciate you are so kind, I'm just a little confused. This is exactly what I am confused of:
If $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ is a $\sigma-$field generated from an uncountable collection of sets named $\mathcal{C}$, then I think that field is uncountable, which I believe is reasonable. Then, I think that $\mathcal{M}$ is countable since all its elements were generated from a countable collection. So how a countable field, can contain an uncountable one? like How can $\sigma(\mathcal{C})\subset \mathcal{M} $? What am I missing? please help

Comment: No, $\cal M$ is the union of *many* $\sigma$-algebras, each generated by a countable set. But the fact is that these $\sigma$-algebras need not be countable themselves, nor there need to be countably many of these.

Comment: Oh I see, So my confusion came from thinking about the cardinality of $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$.  Then, Can we say that since $\mathcal{M}$ contains uncountable many unions of $\sigma(\mathcal{C}_0)$ and moreover, because it is also a $\sigma$-field, then it contains $\mathcal{C}$ and therefore $\sigma{(\mathcal{C})}$. I hope that's the right reasoning..

Comment: Again, the cardinality of $\cal\sigma(C)$ is *never* countable (assuming it's infinite). Note that $\cal C$ is easily a subset of $\cal M$, so $\cal\sigma(C)\subseteq M$ (once you proved that $\cal M$ is actually a $\sigma$-algebra). The other direction follows from the fact that $\cal M$ is a union of sub-algebras of $\cal\sigma(C)$ using similar reasoning.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Understood now. Thanks.

Comment: @Asaf Karaglia. It just so happen that I am answering the same problem as the question above. My question is that how does $\mathscr{M}$ being a sigma algebra implies it contains $\sigma(C)$? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @JrAntalan: It's the smallest one.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong @Asaf Karaglia. $\sigma(C)$ is the smallest sigma algebra containing $C$. But $\mathscr{M}$ is a sigma algebra containing $C$? I am not sure of it.

Comment: @JrAntalan: Yes. And so by virtue of being smallest, $\sigma(C)$ is a subset of any $\sigma$-algebra which contains $C$. In particular $\scr M$.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila. Thank you for your kind reply. My last dilemma is how can I show that $\mathscr{M}$ contains $C$? If we know that (1) $\mathscr{M}$ is the union of all sigma algebras of countable subsets of $C$ and (2) It is a sigma algebra. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @JrAntalan: Maybe I am a bit confused. What exactly is $\scr M$?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila sorry for the confusion I caused you                                                                                 $\mathscr{M}=\bigcup\{\sigma(C_0):\sigma(C_0)\subseteq \sigma(C) \mbox{is countable}\}$.

Comment: @JrAntalan: Right. Well, $\scr M$ clearly contains every countable subset of $C$.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila. I agree, but if that is the case how will it imply $\mathscr{M}$ contains $C$ for those uncountable sets in $C$. Thanks

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong @Asaf Karagila. For those uncountable sets in $C$ it is still in $\mathscr{M}$ since $\mathscr{M}$ is a sigma algebra. If $K$ is a set in $\mathscr{M}$ that is countable, then its complement (which is uncountable?) Is also in $\mathscr{M}$?

Comment: @JrAntalan: You misunderstood the definition, then. $\scr M$ is defined to be the union of $\sigma(C_0)$ for $C_0\subseteq C$ and countable. If $K\in C$, then $\{K\}$ is a countable subset of $C$. This is not about the cardinality of the elements of $C$, but rather the subsets of $C$. So $C$ is the family of sets that you're generating your $\sigma$-algebra from, it is not an element of the algebra in any sort of way or capacity.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila. I see. Thank you for pointing it out. Its clear to me now. Thanks